# Can onViewCreated be called before Activity onCreate finishes?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to redesign some fragments to remove dependencies from the onAttach and onActivityCreated overrides and instead look up the Activity later on in the onViewCreated override.

Are there any cases in the Android application lifecycle where onViewCreated for the fragment is called before Activity onCreate finishes. For example I know that:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

will usually not result in Fragments onAttach being called (assuming the fragment is added to the fragment manager programmatically later on), however in rare cases with configuration updates the fragment manager can recreate the fragments in the super.onCreate which causes the onAttach to be called before onCreate for the activity has finished.

Comment: "remove dependencies from the onAttach and onActivityCreated" why? Any specific reason for doing it?

Comment: Because I have a circular dependency there. Activity onCreate initializes the app logic, which decides which fragment to create and creates it. But in rare cases Activity onCreate super.onCreate is recreating the fragment itself (which is bad - it doesn't know at any given point what the correct fragment is, but anyway). So the fragments, which are referencing the activity in their onAttach, are trying to reference a library which hasnt been configured yet, because the library hasn't decided which fragment to even use yet.

Comment: I think you're facing this when the Activity is recreated (such as in orientation change or when coming back to the Activity) which will have the paramater `Bundle savedInstanceState` non-null.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Fragment LifeCycle]

**onCreate()**
The system calls this when creating the fragment. Within your implementation, you should initialize essential components of the fragment that you want to retain when the fragment is paused or stopped, then resumed.

**onCreateView()**
Called to create the view hierarchy associated with the fragment.

The system calls this when it's time for the fragment to draw its user interface for the first time. To draw a UI for your fragment, you must return a View from this method that is the root of your fragment's layout. You can return null if the fragment does not provide a UI.

Refer [Fragments Life Cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)